# How can I replace brackets to hyphens within Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE function?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm a newbie in regular expressions. I want to replace any text string symbols like (,),[,] to hyphens (for example):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('(<FIO>)', '(', '-') FROM dual;
```

This gives me ORA-12725 error.

Please, explain me, what's wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: I believe you need to escape the parentheses.

Comment: Do you mean '/' symbol? Could you, please give me an example?

Answer (score 3):

To replace symbols, use the [`TRANSLATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions216.htm#SQLRF06145) function, it is less processor-intensive than regular expression functions:

```
SQL> SELECT translate ('(<FIO>)', '()[]', '----') replaced FROM dual;

REPLACED
--------
-<FIO>-
```

Regular expressions are more versatile and can do more complex things but are more expensive. In this case, replacing one character by another is done more efficiently by a specialized function. If you really want to use regular expressions, you could use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions149.htm#i1305521):

```
SQL> SELECT regexp_replace ('[(<FIO>)]', '[]()[]', '-', 1, 0) reg FROM dual;

REG
---------
--<FIO>--
```

Update: If you want to replace only the first symbol, translate won't work. Instead, use:

```
SQL> SELECT regexp_replace ('[(<FIO>)]', '[]()[]', '-', 1, 1) reg FROM dual;

REG
---------
-(<FIO>)]
```

Comment: Thanks, Vincent! But, if I need replace only first appearance in the string?

Comment: This was not obvious from the statements in your question =) See my updated answer

Comment: Yeah, I understood it, sorry)

Comment: It seems, I asked wrong question ..I'll try to explain in detail.. Vincent, could you write me on my email? asv.mclarenfan@gmail.com I write my program code of my function..

Comment: You should edit your question and rephrase it. Asking a correctly and logically articulated question is half the work done in answering it!

Comment: @Sergey - Vincent has answered your question, and your amended requirements. If you asked completely the wrong question then please ask another *new* question, don't try to tack it onto this one or significantly change what this one was asking.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat Have you tested and proved that `translate` is faster than `regexp_replace`? My findings are that in SQL they perform the same while in PL/SQL `regexp_replace` is orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058279/performance-of-regexp-replace-vs-translate-in-oracle

Comment: @colin I got conflicting results as well while testing this with simple examples. However I think it's because of PL/SQL optimization: if you build an example with thousands of distinct strings to convert, `TRANSLATE` is a lot more efficient than `REGEXP`. [Here's an example on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/9872), I tested it on 11.1.0.7.0 and 11.2.0.3.0 and both are a lot faster with `translate`.

Comment: Your regexp is [wrong](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/9880) and slow (because of additional OR-ing).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks, I was wondering why I had to treat the closing bracket differently.