# How to mask a mobile phone number portion with 'X'

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Using Oracle SQL, how can I replace certain numbers with an 'X'.

For example, if I have a random mobile number:

`0400 100 200 or 0400100200`

I would like to mask out the number to:

```
0400 XXX XXX and 0400XXXXXX
```

I have tried using TRANSLATE but unsure if this is the best approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [REGEX_REPLACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm), e.g.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(SUSBTR(PhoneNumber, 5), '[0-9]', 'X')
```

Will replace all numbers after the 4th character with `X', so a full example would be:

```
SELECT  SUSBTR(PhoneNumber, 1, 4) 
            || REGEXP_REPLACE(SUSBTR(PhoneNumber, 5), '[0-9]', 'X') AS Masked
FROM    T;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3bbde/3)**

As has been pointed out in a comment, you can also use `TRANSLATE` as follows:

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(SUBSTR(PhoneNumber, 5), '0123456789', 'XXXXXXXXXX') AS TRANSLATE;
```

I have very little practical experience with Oracle so can't even guess at which one would perform better, the commenter (Alex Poole) does however have a score of 2.3k in Oracle compared to my 53. So if he is suggesting TRANSLATE will run faster, I would not argue. I'd suggest trying both and picking the one that works fastest on your set of data.

Comment: Or [translate](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3bbde/5), which is slightly less compact but might run faster on large volumes of data (if that's at all relevant).

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever done a straight comparison - and it sounds like something I've read and assume to be true - [but others have](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16058279/266304), with mixed results depending on the data. It's probably not worth worrying about unless you have a lot of data and a performance issue; I'm being a bit premature *8-) If speed really matters then indeed the OP should test both, otherwise use whichever you are more comfortable with.

Comment: I went the TRANSLATE. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sample mobile number:

> 1234567890

My output:

> 12xxxxxx90

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),x.MobileNo),1,2)) +
     'xxxxx' +
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),x.MobileNo),LEN(x.MobileNo) - 1, LEN(x.MobileNo)))
     AS MobileNo
FROM TABLENAME x
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

I'd prefer to give an answer:

```
String str = "12345678";
int len = str.length() - 3;
StringBuilder replace = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    replace.append( "X" );
replace.append( len >= 0 ? str.substring( len ) : "" );
```

Comment: That doesn't look much like SQL. Why have you given a Java solution?