# Oracle Regexp_replace multiple occurrence

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Hi I want to append a letter C to a string if it starts with a number .
Also if it has any punctuation then replace with underscore _
Eg : 5-2-2-1  ==> C5_2_2_1

I tried ,but I am not able to replace the multiple occurrence of the punctuation. I am missing some simple thing, I cant get it.

```
SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE('9-1-1','^(\d)(-),'C\1_' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select (case when substr(val, 1, 1) between '0' and '9' then 'C' else '' end) ||
       regexp_replace(val, '([-+.,;:'"!])', '_')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply !!,Just out of curiosity if there a way to do it in once regular expression function

Comment: @RajA . . . I don't think there is a way to do this with one function.

Comment: ..Hmmm I was thinking if anyhow we can capture more than one occurance of a character..But its okay, I will use this..Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT case when REGEXP_LIKE('9-1-1','^[[:digit:]]') then 'C' END 
       || REGEXP_REPLACE('9-1-1', '[[:punct:]]', '_')
FROM DUAL;
```

`[:digit:]` any digit
`[:punct:]` punctuation symbol

if you have a lot of rows with different values then try to avoid regex:

```
SELECT case when substr('9-1-1',1,1) between '0' and '9' then 'C' end
       || translate('9-1-1', ',.!-', '_')
FROM DUAL;
```

Check here for example: [Performance of regexp_replace vs translate in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058279/performance-of-regexp-replace-vs-translate-in-oracle)

Comment: Thanks a lot it works! I was just trying to minimize multiple functions because I'll be scanning this through millions of rows

Comment: @Raj A I've added some more info. I didn't know about millions of rows

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort and the link!!